# How do I slow done a node JS event listener?

Tags: node.js, arduino, hid

I'm trying to use a wireless controller with my code. I'm using node HID, and currently am just trying to write some code that will output "Tap" when a button is pressed the first time and output "untap" the second time. The only problem I am facing is that a single tap will set off both if statements, because the listener event refreshes way too fast. is there any way I could slow it down?

```
    device.on ("data", function (data){

        if (data[4]===31&&(!pressed)){

            device.pause();
            console.log("tap");

            pressed=true;

        }

        if (data[4]===31&&(pressed)){

            device.pause();

            console.log("untap");

            pressed=false;

        }



    device.resume();
    console.log(data[4]);
    console.log(pressed);

    });
```

(pressed is a variable declared earlier)

Comment: I don't think you really want to slow anything down... I think you're looking for "debounce".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `else if` instead. At the moment, you set `pressed` to `true` if the first `if` is fulfilled, but if the first `if` is fulfilled, then the next

```
if (data[4]===31&&(pressed)){
```

will be `true` because both `data[4] === 31` (since the first `if` was fulfilled) *and* you just set `pressed` to `true`.

That'll cut down the logs from `tap, untap, tap, untap, tap, untap, tap, untap` to `tap, untap, tap, untap`, but it sounds like the `data` event is also being fired twice on a single tap, so add a slight delay before the listener's main body can be called again:

```
let lastDataCall = 0;
device.on("data", function(data) {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (now - lastDataCall < 20) { // 20 milliseconds
    return;
  }
  lastDataCall = now;
  if (data[4] === 31) {
    device.pause();
    if (!pressed) {
      console.log("tap");
      pressed = true;
    } else if ((pressed)) {
      console.log("untap");
      pressed = false;
    }
  }
  device.resume();
  console.log(data[4]);
  console.log(pressed);
});
```

(if the only code you have in the `data` handler relates to tapping/untapping, you can trim things down by `return`ing early if `data[4] !== 31`, it'll probably make the code a bit more readable)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, which is probably why I didn't think of it. Thanks

Comment: Sadly this doesn't actually work. it still spits out "tap, untap, tap, untap. when pressing once.

Comment: Was your original code actually logging `tap, untap, tap, untap, tap, untap, tap, untap` on a single tap-untap? I thought you said it was just duplicated once, which the `else if` should fix

Comment: Yep. that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: sorry, for some reason I couldn't see your whole comment. It was outputting tap and untap multiple times. Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: Sounds like there are two issues, the `else if` issue and the `data` event being fired twice for every tap *and* twice for every untap - add a timer state to make sure that the main callback can only run, say, 15 milliseconds after the last call.

Comment: Not quite sure how I'd do that. Could you show me an example?

Comment: I did - see the answer. I don't know anything about HID, but you *might* be able to use `Promise.resolve` (which would be a lot more elegant) instead of using dates.

Comment: Yay, that works, except 20 ms was still too fast. 100ms is fine though.